# Converting JSON file to GEXF file

Tags: javascript, json, echarts

Is there anyway to convert JSON file to GEXF file?

I'm currently using this echarts circular layout graph (https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graph-circular-layout).

However, the JSON file has to be converted to GEXF file format for it to be used in the graph.

Note: My codes are in Javascript.

Thank you!

**Updated with codes**

Below is the sample codes of using the circular layout graph. It's getting the data from gexf file. However my input data for the graph is in JSON file.

```
myChart.showLoading();
$.get(ROOT_PATH + '/data/asset/data/les-miserables.gexf', function (xml) {
myChart.hideLoading();

var graph = echarts.dataTool.gexf.parse(xml);
var categories = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    categories[i] = {
        name: '类目' + i
    };
}
graph.nodes.forEach(function (node) {
    node.itemStyle = null;
    node.value = node.symbolSize;
    node.symbolSize /= 1.5;
    node.label = {
        normal: {
            show: node.symbolSize > 10
        }
    };
    node.category = node.attributes.modularity_class;
});
option = {
    title: {
        text: 'Les Miserables',
        subtext: 'Circular layout',
        top: 'bottom',
        left: 'right'
    },
    tooltip: {},
    legend: [{
        data: categories.map(function (a) {
            return a.name;
        })
    }],
    animationDurationUpdate: 1500,
    animationEasingUpdate: 'quinticInOut',
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Les Miserables',
            type: 'graph',
            layout: 'circular',
            circular: {
                rotateLabel: true
            },
            data: graph.nodes,
            links: graph.links,
            categories: categories,
            roam: true,
            label: {
                position: 'right',
                formatter: '{b}'
            },
            lineStyle: {
                color: 'source',
                curveness: 0.3
            }
        }
    ]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
}, 'xml');
```

**Github Sample Codes**

1. The github of this graph has the source code for the JSON file (codes) that it uses to populate the graph -> https://github.com/hecore/echart_demo/blob/master/data/hecore.json
2. I'm not sure how did the codes transform to this -> https://github.com/hecore/echart_demo/blob/master/data/les-miserables.json
3. Lastly, this is the file that they used to populate in the echarts circular layout graph in .gexf format -> https://github.com/hecore/echart_demo/blob/master/data/les-miserables.gexf

Comment: If you have sample code you can add here.

Comment: @SSK question is updated with codes =)

Answer (score 0):

You could install Gephi (https://gephi.org/users/install/), then the JSON Exporter plugin for Gephi (https://gephi.org/plugins/#/plugin/jsonexporter-plugin). Then open the gexf file in Gephi and go to file>export>graph file>json graph.  I'm not sure if it's exactly the format you need, but could be a starting point.